# CamelCase for property in data response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have one API that return that :

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Data": [
    {
      "ID": 1,
      "ProcedureID": 1,
      "Channel": "Channel 1",
      "ResolvedTime": "Anytime",
      "Description": "No description"
    }
  ],
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Message": ""
}
```

but actually I want is :

```
{
  "Success": true,
  "Data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "procedureID": 1,
      "channel": "Channel 1",
      "resolvedTime": "Anytime",
      "description": "No description"
    }
  ],
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "Message": ""
}
```

what are happening with my list "Data", I just want the property names of all the objects inside that list formatted in camelCase. How can I do that? I'm using EF core 6 and my Program.cs already have this line:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>{
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;});
```

Comment: Try `services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options=>options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy=null;});`

Comment: @XinranShen I tried but it didn't work

Comment: I think your setup would create the Json based on the spelling of the property. Try changing id, channel etc to lowercase on the class itself.

Comment: _"I'm using EF core 6"_ - That doesn't seem like it should be relevant. Are you returning your database models directly?

Comment: @IAmGroot I can't rename of the property on those class because my Project Manager do not allow

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama I return this list through another class that give Success, Data, StatusCode, Message

Comment: @louis26, If you don't add any `AddNewtonsoftJson()` and just `builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options=>options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy=null;});`, It  doesn't work? I test it and It works fine in my project.

Comment: @XinranShen yep, It's not work for me

Comment: Are there any other settings in your program.cs? In Generally,  the configuration I provided above will be successful